# Запуск метода содержащего Task.Run в другом методе через Task.Run

Tags: c#, многопоточность, task

Как будет выполняться код? Будет 2 потока? Как я понимаю будет выполняться так:

1. выделяется поток из пула в Method1
2. выделяется поток из пула внутри Method2

```
public async void Method1()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Method2());
}
private async void Method2()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
         //код
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task.Run` запускает код в потоке из пула и возвращает `Task`, ожидающий окончания выполнения кода. Больше он ничего не делает. Все остальное зависит от контекста синхронизации, и если такового нет, то показанный код может использовать до 5 потоков.

Давайте посчитаем, я пронумерую строчки кода номерами потоков

```cs
public async void Method1()
{ // 1
    await Task.Run(() => Method2() /* 2 */);
} // 3
private async Task Method2()
{ // 2
    await Task.Run(() =>
    { // 4
         
    });
} // 5
```

То есть возврат в метод после await может быть в любом другом потоке, не обязательно в том, из которого этот await начинался. Вот такая вот асинхронность.

И не используйте `async void`, я исправил ошибку, из-за которой этот код бы вообще не работал как надо.

[Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).